# How to avoid starting previously installed OSGi bundles at very first

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm using apache-felix file-install to monitor a directory and start bundles.

My problem is all bundles exist in directory (those are all installed and started by felix file install) are activating at very first whenever I starting OSGi server.

I want to activate all installed bundles at a specific start level.

Comment: Why? It's best practice to start all OSGi bundles.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I'm using peaberry dependency injection. So that I need to start some bundles first to make services available to use in later bundles.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Is there any possible to tell Equinox to avoid caching installed bundles. I'll be able to install and start my (required)bundles everytime OSGi starts. Is this the right way?

Comment: There is no need to start bundles in a specific order if you are using a DI framework like Peaberry.